# ffmpeg mp3 conversion

Tags: mp3, ffmpeg

was to convert several thousand MP3 files, and get this for some files:
ffmpeg -t 45 -i "my_mp3.mp3" -y "new_mp3.mp3" 
FFmpeg version 0.5-svn17737+3:0.svn20090303-1ubuntu6, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al. 
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --extra-version=svn17737+3:0.svn20090303-1ubuntu6 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-libdc1394 --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-armv6t2 --disable-armvfp --disable-neon --disable-altivec --disable-vis --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0 
  libavcodec    52.20. 0 / 52.20. 0 
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0 
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0 
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0 
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1 
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0 
  built on Apr 10 2009 23:18:41, gcc: 4.3.3 
my_mp3.mp3: could not find codec parameters

what could be the problem?

Comment: This seems like a question for SuperUser.com as I don't see any actual code or programming question.

Answer (score 1):

problem was solved with adding `-f mp3`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds that there are some files, which are not actually MP3 files, but just have the extension, and that they are not actually audio files or use a codec not understood by ffmpg.

Have you checked the files in question?